# The name "currentsprite'' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#

I have a C# (with monogame) project (visual studios 2015) with a pre-made code given. Following the documentation, I have done as it asks. But, even after the variables have been declared before any for of loops or conditional statements, I am still getting error code cs0103. Below is the code where it gives me the red underline:

```
            int spriteNumber = rand.Next(0, 2);

            // STUDENTS: uncomment the lines below and change sprite0, sprite1, and sprite2
            //      to the three different names of your sprite variables
            if (spritenumber == 0)
            {
                currentsprite = t0;
            }
            else if (spritenumber == 1)
            {
                currentsprite = t1;
            }
            else if (spritenumber == 2)
            {
                currentsprite = t2;
            }
```

My error comes in the if statements after I have declared sprite number, and current sprite also doesn't get considered.(currentsprite and spritenumber(This has a random answer using Random class) have been declared before.

Comment: Where do you get the error?

Comment: missing ';' or missing } would be my guess.

Comment: If at least the variable name was posted, instead of "...

Comment: Especially if the code depends on third party libraries. The funny thing is that a lot of people ask questions such as this and then... pffft! Gone! Where do you go after asking your questions, good people? Where? :'(

Comment: Which line give you error?

Comment: Sorry about the mess, I am new to this site.

Comment: P.s. use [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, with your edit the error is pretty clear to me:

```
int spriteNumber = rand.Next(0,2);

if (spritenumber == 0)
{
    currentsprite = t0;
}
else if (spritenumber == 1)
{
    currentsprite = t1;
}
else if (spritenumber == 2)
{
    currentsprite = t2;
}
```

C# is case-sensitive, so `spriteNumber` and `spritenumber` are not considered to be the same variable. Either change your `if`s or the declaration of the variable:

```
int spritenumber = rand.Next(0, 2);
```

Comment: It worked. There was some case based issues (It was a pre designed code btw). Anyway, thank you